# How to solve integral of second-degree exponential function?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the internal of the second-degree exponential function. But Solve fails to give the solution. Is there any way to get the solution?

By the way, I don't understand the ability limitation of Mathematica when solving this kind of complex equations. Is there any introduction to this?

Thank you very much!

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
w = 10;
r = 25;
s = 5;
phi = 1/3;
phj = 1/3;
tauij = 3;
cij = 25;
cji = 25;

  lhs11 = r - w + (cij - tauij - r)/(1 - phj) *
    Integrate[
     1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*Exp[-(xi - 3)^2/2]*1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*
      Exp[-(xj - 3)^2/2], {xi, 0, Q}, {xj, Q + Q - xi, 
      Q + 1/phj*(Q - xi)}] + (s - r) Integrate[
     1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*Exp[-(xi - 3)^2/2]*1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*
      Exp[-(xj - 3)^2/2], {xi, 0, Q}, {xj, Q, 
      Q + Q - xi}]   + (phi (r - cji))/(1 - phi)*
    Integrate[
     1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*Exp[-(xi - 3)^2/2]*1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*
      Exp[-(xj - 3)^2/2], {xj, 0, Q}, {xi, Q + Q - xj, 
      Q + 1/phi*(Q - xj)}] + (cji - r) *
    Integrate[
     1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*Exp[-(xi - 3)^2/2]*1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*
      Exp[-(xj - 3)^2/2], {xj, 0, Q}, {xi, Q, Q + Q - xj}] + (s - r)*
    Integrate[
     1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*Exp[-(xi - 3)^2/2]*1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*
      Exp[-(xj - 3)^2/2], {xi, 0, Q}, {xj, 0, Q}];
Solve[lhs11 == 0, Q > 0, Reals]
```

The result is
[image]

But can I know the exact value of Q?

Comment: It might help if you wrote your integrals using `Integrate[... , {xj,...}, {xi,...}]` instead of using `\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\),...` because your code doesn't work if I copy-paste it and I needed to manually fix these lines. Be careful with the order. Also the outer integrals take too long and the expressions contain transcendental functions and `Erf`, so I doubt Solve is going to work.

Comment: Sorry, I just copy my code from the notebook. It works when I paste them to a new notebook. I will see how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi~I have fix the format as you have suggested and I also append the result given by Solve. Do you have any other suggestions if I want to get the exact value of Q? Or I want to know if the solution Q is a unique real number which is bigger than 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it's possible to find an exact value, so I've converted your `Integrate`'s to `NIntegrate` and turned `lhs11` into a function where `Q` is pattern tested with `NumericQ`. This allows me to `NMinimize` the square of `Abs[lhs11[Q]]` and find a numerical solution `Q -> 3.79933`:

```
w = 10;
r = 25;
s = 5;
phi = 1/3;
phj = 1/3;
tauij = 3;
cij = 25;
cji = 25;

lhs11[Q_?NumericQ] := 
 r - w + (cij - tauij - r)/(1 - phj)*
   NIntegrate[
    1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*Exp[-(xi - 3)^2/2]*1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*
     Exp[-(xj - 3)^2/2], {xi, 0, Q}, {xj, Q + Q - xi, 
     Q + 1/phj*(Q - xi)}] + (s - r) NIntegrate[
    1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*Exp[-(xi - 3)^2/2]*1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*
     Exp[-(xj - 3)^2/2], {xi, 0, Q}, {xj, Q, 
     Q + Q - xi}] + (phi (r - cji))/(1 - phi)*
   NIntegrate[
    1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*Exp[-(xi - 3)^2/2]*1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*
     Exp[-(xj - 3)^2/2], {xj, 0, Q}, {xi, Q + Q - xj, 
     Q + 1/phi*(Q - xj)}] + (cji - r)*
   NIntegrate[
    1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*Exp[-(xi - 3)^2/2]*1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*
     Exp[-(xj - 3)^2/2], {xj, 0, Q}, {xi, Q, Q + Q - xj}] + (s - r)*
   NIntegrate[
    1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*Exp[-(xi - 3)^2/2]*1/Sqrt[2 Pi]*
     Exp[-(xj - 3)^2/2], {xi, 0, Q}, {xj, 0, Q}]

NMinimize[{Abs[lhs11[Q]]^2, Q > 0}, Q \[Element] Reals]

(* result: {7.38594*10^-17, {Q -> 3.79933}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So does this imply the solution is not unique?

Comment: Try `ListPlot[{#, lhs11[#]} & /@ Range[0, 10, .1]]` - you'll see that for $Q>0$ there is only one point it crosses the x-axis.

Comment: Thank you so much!